# angular $watch is not triggered but model is updated in template from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm not able to catch the change event of a model in Angular. Everything works fine, I can view the updated model value in the template, but not available in the controller.

This is my code:
controller:

```
//watches the date selector
    $scope.$watch('startDate', function (value1, value2) {
        console.log (value1, value2);
    });
```

template:

```
{{startDate}}{{endDate}}
<daterangepicker readonly start="startDate" end="endDate" format="currentUser.settings.dateFormat" options="daterangeoptions"></daterangepicker>
```

directive:

```
//daterange picker
myAppDirectives
.directive('daterangepicker', function ($parse, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            options: '=options',
            start: '=start',
            end: '=end',
            format: '=format'
        },
        compile: function (element, attrs){
            //debugger;
            //var initialVal = attrs.startDate + attrs.endDate;
            var htmlText = '<div class="input-append pull-right">';
            htmlText += '<input type="text" readonly="" id="range" value="" />';
            htmlText += '<input type="hidden" name="startDate" ng-model="startDate" value="" />';
            htmlText += '<input type="hidden" name="endDate" ng-model="endDate" value="" />';
            htmlText += '<span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span></div>';
            element.replaceWith(htmlText);
            //return function, does all the logic
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var daterangecallback = function (start, end) {
                    //let angular know change happened to $scope
                    scope.start = start;
                    scope.end = end;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
                $timeout(function(){ 
                    var range = element.find('#range');
                    range.daterangepicker (scope.options, daterangecallback);
                    range.val(moment(scope.options.startDate).format(scope.options.format) + ' - ' + moment(scope.options.endDate).format(scope.options.format));
                });
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: You should probably watch `start` and not `startDate`.

Comment: It looks like this has nothing to do with the directive, since startDate is defined in the controller. If startDate is an object, you have to deep watch it (second function param of $watch set to true).

Comment: @Codezilla I've tried with start and doesn't work.

Comment: @Narretz I've did deep watch on the function with no results.

Comment: Please add a plunker with a minimum non-working example. Your code examples are a good start, but they lack context. E.g. I don't know in which scope you are watching startDate.

Comment: It's probably a scope issue. You should try to use a nested property. Add this in your controller : $scope.values = {}. Then send values to the directive and use values.startdate.... nested properties are not in read only in child scopes.